# Two-color hitting set

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Let $n,m$ be a positive integer with $m\ge 2n$. In the set $M=\{1,2,\dots,m\}$, some elements are black and others are white. Given $2n$ nonempty subsets of $M$, the task is to determine whether there exists a subset $T\subseteq M$ consisting of $n$ black and $n$ white elements such that each of the $2n$ subsets has a nonempty intersection with $T$. Can this be done in polynomial time?

Without the color constraint, this is very similar to the [hitting set problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/127261/why-is-the-hitting-set-problem-in-np). Choosing a subset $T$ of size $2n$ without the color constraint is easy, by choosing one representative from each of the $2n$ subsets and, if the union of these representatives has size less than $2n$, fill in with arbitrary remaining elements of $M$. But having $n$ black and $n$ white elements is not always possible, for instance if there are not enough elements of one color.

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that this could be done in polynomial time, because you'd have to be able to answer correctly on instances with, e.g., exactly $n$ white elements that don't appear in any of the subsets, requiring us to hit the $2n$ subsets with exactly $n$ black elements. That doesn't quite reduce it to the fully-general hitting set problem, but it seems close enough to probably still be NP-hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can this be done in polynomial time?

No, it cannot (unless P equals NP, of course).

Consider the case where all the $2n$ sets only contain elements that are colored (say) black. Finding a "white-black hitting set" with $n$ pairs is now exactly the same as finding a regular hitting set with n elements.
A reduction from Hitting Set

> Find a set of at most $k$ elements that hits all sets in the collection $\mathcal{C}$, where $\mathcal{C} = r$

to your specific scenario

> Find a set of $n$ pairs of white and black elements that hits all sets in the collection $\mathcal{C}$, where $|\mathcal{C}| = 2n$

follows easily. The only extra thing to take care of is if $2k < r$ (just add $r-2k$ black elements to $M$ and make each one a singleton set, now $n = r-k$), or if $2k > r$ (just take some arbitrary set $C\in \mathcal{C}$, add $2k-r$ extra elements to $M$ and, for each one make a set containing the union of it and $C$).